# How to GetWindowDC of different application?

Tags: windows, gdi

I am writing an application (application a) that will automate certain procedures of another application (application b) based on a pixel color of application b.

I am trying to use the windows function [GetPixel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

One of the parameters of this function required the device context, I need to use the window device context rather than the whole screen, [GetWindowDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

From application a, how can I get the window device context of application b?

Will this method work for getting the pixel color of application b while application b is not in focus or is minimized? If not, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `GetWindowDC` that you mentioned would allow you to get the window device context of app b.  Are you asking how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the [`WM_PRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`WM_PRINTCLIENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to a window to get it to draw into your own DC handle, and this will work even if the window is minimized. The only problem is that WM_PRINT will call WM_PRINTCLIENT, and WM_PRINTCLIENT must be handled by the application itself - Windows does not provide a default implementation.